# Conditionally skipping an ANTLR lexer rule based on current line number

Tags: antlr, lexer

I have this pair of rules in my ANTLR lexer grammar, which match the same pattern, but have mutually exclusive predicates:

```
MAGIC:        '#' ~[\r\n]* {getLine() == 1}? ;
HASH_COMMENT: '#' ~[\r\n]* {getLine() != 1}? -> skip;
```

When I look at the tokens in the ANTLR Preview, I see:

[image: Screenshot of ANTLR Preview]

So it seems like the predicate isn't being used, and regardless of the line I'm on, the token comes out as MAGIC.

I also tried a different approach to try and work around this:

```
tokens { MAGIC }

HASH_COMMENT: '#' ~[\r\n]* {if (getLine() == 1) setType(MAGIC); else skip();};
```

But now, both come out as HASH_COMMENT:

[image: Another screenshot of ANTLR Preview]

I really expected the first attempt using two predicates to work, so that was surprising, but now it seems like the action doesn't work either, which is even more odd.

How do I make this work?

I'd rather not try to match "#usda ..." as a different token because that comment could occur further down the file, and it should be treated as a normal comment unless it's on the first line.

Comment: What "ANTLR Preview"? Of what plugin?? "grun" aka the "TestRig"? Or are you using Intellij?

Comment: [Limitations](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4#limitations)

Comment: @kaby76 IntelliJ's, yeah... so those limitations are interesting, it suggests that what I have now might actually work in the real thing, just not in the tester. :(

Comment: That's right. I suggest you run 'java -cp "c:/Users/Kenne/Downloads/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar;." org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig grammar start-symbol test.txt'. That should work for Windows. Make sure to build your app first. I think there's an Issue in Github to make the plugin use the generated parser rather than this interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to force semantics in the parse step. The letter combination is a HASH_COMMENT, period.

Instead I would handle that as normal syntax and handle anything special you might need in the step after parsing. For example:

```
document: HASH_COMMENT? content EOF;
```

This way you define a possible HASH_COMMENT (which you might interpret as MAGIC later, without using such a token type) before any content. Might not be line one, but before anything else (which resembles real document better, where you can have whitespaces before your hash comment).

Comment: I don't think you _can_ have spaces before this particular magic line though, mind you. If I look at the lexer in the usd source code itself, they're very particular about it being on the first line. Still might not stop me doing it this way, because newlines are also kept in their syntax.

Comment: You can check the line in your semantic phase and if the first HASH_COMMENT is not on the first line throw a syntax error. This also allows you to tell the user exactly what is wrong (which would not be possible with your predicate solution).